# JAXB adapter from Calendar to Joda DateTime

Tags: java, web-services, calendar, cxf, jodatime

I'm trying to write a JAXB XMLAdapter so that xs:dateTime fields are not created as `XMLGregorianCalendar`, but as joda `DateTime`.

But it does not work as expected, especially the autogenerated Adapter to wire between the types is auto-generated somehow completely wrong (wsdl2java). But why?

```
  <jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime" xmlType="xsd:dateTime" 
      parseMethod="my.DateTimeAdapter.unmarshal"
      printMethod="my.DateTimeAdapter.marshal" />
  </jaxb:globalBindings>

public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<DateTime, Calendar>{

    @Override
    public Calendar unmarshal(DateTime date) throws Exception {
        return date.toGregorianCalendar();
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime marshal(Calendar date) throws Exception {
        return new DateTime(date);
    }
}
```

Result (auto generated):

```
public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>
{


    public Date unmarshal(String value) {
        return (javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(value));
    }

    public String marshal(Date value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(value));
    }

}
```

Why is the result an adapter with `String, Date` instead of my types defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, also for my personal reference:

1. You should use `xjc:javaType` to define the `XMLAdapter` directly. Otherwise cxf would auto generate further adapters that have to map to your own static methods.

   ```
   <jaxb:globalBindings>
       <xjc:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime"
           xmlType="xs:dateTime"
           adapter="path.to.MyTimeAdapter" />
   </jaxb:globalBindings>
   ```
2. You have to marshal from `String` to your desired class, not from `XmlGregorianCalendar`:

   public class MyTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter {
       @Override
       public DateTime unmarshal(String date) throws Exception {
           return new DateTime(date);
       }

   ```
   @Override
   public String marshal(DateTime date) throws Exception {
       return date.toGregorianCalendar().toString();
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the XMLDateTimeAdapter/XMLLocalDateAdapter from https://github.com/ultraq/jaxb-utilities instead of reinventing the wheel.